# Удаление строки в файле при условии

Tags: c++, файлы, структуры

Нужно описать структуру, вывести её на экран и записать в файл, а потом удалить строчку с введённой длительностью (одно из полей структуры).

Код у меня есть, но он удалял по номеру строки, я поставил условие (если Введенная длительность равна, той что по циклу (i-тый), то есть один из структуры, то мы удаляем). Строки удаления не менял. Может проблема в этом?

```
if(!(i_number_line_now == input_duration)) {   
    line_file_text.insert(line_file_text.size(),line); /*дабавить строку*/  
    /*добавить перенос на слудующую строку*/  
    line_file_text.insert(line_file_text.size(),"\r\n"); 
}
```

вот тут проблема

Comment: Может, и в этом. Без как минимум кода сказать сложно.

Comment: Я сейчас пытался отправить, но там ограничение

Comment: @graphgfx Отправьте только ту часть кода, которая нужна для исправления, либо [закиньте код на этот сайт](https://ideone.com/) и дайте ссылку.

Comment: @Harry https://ideone.com/tbjqAH

Comment: if(!(i_number_line_now == input_duration))
   {
       line_file_text.insert(line_file_text.size(),line); /*дабавить строку*/
       /*добавить перенос на слудующую строку*/
       line_file_text.insert(line_file_text.size(),"\r\n");
 
   }
 } вот тут проблема

Comment: Прочитайте [эту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) статейку, пожалуйста и отредактируйте свой вопрос соответственно, тогда в полезных ответах не будет отбоя, а сейчас, я думаю, мало кто понял, в чем проблема. **Представьте, что вы сами видите свой вопрос впервые. Всё ли вам понятно?**

Comment: @asianirish спасибо, учту

Comment: Я по-новой создал:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059840/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83