# Проблема с удалением определенной строки в файле(по содержимому)

Tags: c++, файлы

мне нужно записать структуру в файл, а потом, введя длительность фильма, удалить строчку с этой длительностью.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
    struct Movie
    {
        string title, director;
        int duration;
        string cost;
    };

int main(void)
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    const int size = 5;
    Movie film[]=
    {
     {"IT","Андрес Мускеттi",135,"35 млн $"},
     {"Avengers:Endgame","Ентонi Руссо",181,"356 млн $"},
     {"Terminator","Джеймс Кемерон",108,"6.4 млн $"},
     {"Star Wars:The Last Jedi","Раян Джонсон",152,"200 млн $"},
     {"Spider-Man:Homecoming","Джон Воттс",130,"175 млн $"},
    };
    string path = "Movie.txt";
    ofstream fout;  //Створюємо документ для запису
    fout.open("Movie.txt",fstream::app);
    if(!fout.is_open()) cout<<"Помилка!\n";
    else
        {
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
                {
                    cout<<setw(22)<<film[i].title<<"\t"<<film[i].director<<"\t"<<film[i].duration<<"\t"<<film[i].cost<<"\n";
                    fout<<setw(22)<<film[i].title<<"\t"<<film[i].director<<"\t"<<film[i].duration<<"\t"<<film[i].cost<<"\n";
                }
                int n, number_string;
                /*cout<<"\nВведiть номер рядка i кiлькiсть їх виведень: ";
                cin>>n>>number_string;
                n-=1;
            for(int j=0; j<number_string; j++)
            {
                fout<<setw(22)<<film[n].title<<"\t"<<film[n].director<<"\t"<<film[n].duration<<"\t"<<film[n].cost<<"\n";
            }
        } */
        fout.close();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ifstream file_in;

  file_in.open("Movie.txt");

 if(!file_in)
  {
    std::cerr << "Невозможно открыть файл : Movie.txt" << std::endl;
    return (0);
  }
  std::cout <<"Введите длительность фильма для удаления :"<< std::endl;
  int i_number_duration_delete; //для хранения номера строки который нужно удалить
  std::cin >> i_number_duration_delete;

  std::string line; //для хранения строки
  std::string line_file_text; //для хранения текста файла

 while(getline(file_in,line))
 {

    for(int j=1; j<=size; j++)
   if(!(film[j].duration == i_number_duration_delete))
   {
       line_file_text.insert(line_file_text.size(),line);

       line_file_text.insert(line_file_text.size(),"\r\n");

    break;
   }
 }

 file_in.close();

 std::ofstream file_out;

 file_out.open ("Movie.txt",std::ios::trunc);

 file_out.write(line_file_text.c_str(), line_file_text.size());

 file_out.close();

  return (1);
}
```

Comment: Вот весь код: https://ideone.com/8b3coY
А вот часть с которой проблема: https://ideone.com/N6pxlX

Comment: Код в вопрос а не в комментарии.

Comment: @ヒミコ он считает ссылку с этого сайта, как код, по-этому не получилось. Спасибо)

Comment: Все, проблема решена, я понял в каком условии проблема. Если что, то я просто заменил while на for(int i=0;getline(file_in,line);i++),и все